# Do we need to upload the spark binary package to http/s3/hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am trying to run a spark-shell on a mesos cluster.

From [this documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#uploading-spark-package), we need to upload the spark binary package to a location available for Mesos.

Can't we just provide the direct link, from which we download the spark package, to `spark.executor.uri`? Currently : http://apache.mediamirrors.org/spark/spark-2.4.0/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

Answer (score 0):

If the Mesos agents can access the public internet, that should work. The downside may be slower downloading times etc.

Comment: Can we do this even without building Spark? I have seen many people doing the `sbt clean assembly` before uploading the package to hdfs.